# mysql 8 problem in create table return me erro r 1064

Tags: mysql

why when i create this table with mysql  workbench return me  error ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''app_terminal'.'Bin_ExchangeInfo' (
'id' MEDIUMINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
't' at line 1
i think is  all ok in my code
my code

```
CREATE TABLE 'app_terminal'.'Bin_ExchangeInfo' (
   'id' MEDIUMINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
   'timezone' CHAR NULL,
   'serverTime' TIMESTAMP NULL,
   'rateLimits_0' CHAR NULL,
   'rateLimits_1' CHAR NULL,
   'rateLimits_2' CHAR NULL,
   'rateLimits_3' CHAR NULL,
   'rateLimits_4' CHAR NULL,
   'interval_0' CHAR NULL,
   'interval_1' CHAR NULL,
   'interval_2' CHAR NULL,
   'interval_3' CHAR NULL,
   'interval_4' CHAR NULL,
   'intervalNum_0' TINYINT NULL,
   'intervalNum_1' TINYINT NULL,
   'intervalNum_2' TINYINT NULL,
   'intervalNum_3' TINYINT NULL,
   'intervalNum_4' TINYINT NULL,
   'limit_0' MEDIUMINT NULL,
   'limit_1' MEDIUMINT NULL,
   'limit_2' MEDIUMINT NULL,
   'limit_3' MEDIUMINT NULL,
   'limit_4' MEDIUMINT NULL,
   'symbol' CHAR NULL,
   'status' CHAR NULL,
   'baseAsset' CHAR NULL,
   'baseAssetPrecision' TINYINT NULL,
   'quoteAsset' CHAR NULL,
   'quotePrecision' TINYINT NULL,
   'quoteAssetPrecision' TINYINT NULL,
   'baseCommissionPrecision' TINYINT NULL,
   'quoteCommissionPrecision' TINYINT NULL,
   'orderTypes_0' CHAR NULL,
   'orderTypes_1' CHAR NULL,
   'orderTypes_2' CHAR NULL,
   'orderTypes_3' CHAR NULL,
   'orderTypes_4' CHAR NULL,
   'icebergAllowed' CHAR NULL,
   'ocoAllowed' CHAR NULL,
   'quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed' CHAR NULL,
   'isSpotTradingAllowed' CHAR NULL,
   'isMarginTradingAllowed' CHAR NULL,
   'filterType_0' CHAR NULL,
   'minPrice'  FLOAT NULL,
   'maxPrice'  FLOAT NULL,
   'tickSize'  FLOAT NULL,
   'filterType_1' CHAR NULL,
   'multiplierUp' TINYINT NULL,
   'multiplierDown'  FLOAT NULL,
   'avgPriceMins_f1' TINYINT NULL,
   'filterType_2' CHAR NULL,
   'minQty_f2'  FLOAT NULL,
   'maxQty_f2'  FLOAT NULL,
   'stepSize_f2'  FLOAT NULL,
   'filterType_3' CHAR NULL,
   'minNotional'  FLOAT NULL,
   'applyToMarket' CHAR NULL,
   'avgPriceMins_f3' TINYINT NULL,
   'filterType_4' CHAR NULL,
   'limit_f4' TINYINT NULL,
   'filterType_5' CHAR NULL,
   'minQty_f5'  FLOAT NULL,
   'maxQty_f5'  FLOAT NULL,
   'stepSize_f5'  FLOAT NULL,
   'filterType_6' CHAR NULL,
   'maxNumOrders' TINYINT NULL,
   'filterType_7' CHAR NULL,
   'maxNumAlgoOrders' TINYINT NULL,
   'permissions_0' CHAR NULL,
   'permissions_1' CHAR NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
PRIMARY KEY ('id')
COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Use backticks (`) instead of single quotes (').

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

With schema and table names you need to use back ticks, not single quotes. Single quotes are for string literals.

```
CREATE TABLE `app_terminal`.`Bin_ExchangeInfo` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    `timezone` CHAR NULL,
    `serverTime` TIMESTAMP NULL,
    `rateLimits_0` CHAR NULL,
    `rateLimits_1` CHAR NULL,
    `rateLimits_2` CHAR NULL,
    `rateLimits_3` CHAR NULL,
    `rateLimits_4` CHAR NULL,
    `interval_0` CHAR NULL,
    `interval_1` CHAR NULL,
    `interval_2` CHAR NULL,
    `interval_3` CHAR NULL,
    `interval_4` CHAR NULL,
    `intervalNum_0` TINYINT NULL,
    `intervalNum_1` TINYINT NULL,
    `intervalNum_2` TINYINT NULL,
    `intervalNum_3` TINYINT NULL,
    `intervalNum_4` TINYINT NULL,
    `limit_0` MEDIUMINT NULL,
    `limit_1` MEDIUMINT NULL,
    `limit_2` MEDIUMINT NULL,
    `limit_3` MEDIUMINT NULL,
    `limit_4` MEDIUMINT NULL,
    `symbol` CHAR NULL,
    `status` CHAR NULL,
    `baseAsset` CHAR NULL,
    `baseAssetPrecision` TINYINT NULL,
    `quoteAsset` CHAR NULL,
    `quotePrecision` TINYINT NULL,
    `quoteAssetPrecision` TINYINT NULL,
    `baseCommissionPrecision` TINYINT NULL,
    `quoteCommissionPrecision` TINYINT NULL,
    `orderTypes_0` CHAR NULL,
    `orderTypes_1` CHAR NULL,
    `orderTypes_2` CHAR NULL,
    `orderTypes_3` CHAR NULL,
    `orderTypes_4` CHAR NULL,
    `icebergAllowed` CHAR NULL,
    `ocoAllowed` CHAR NULL,
    `quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed` CHAR NULL,
    `isSpotTradingAllowed` CHAR NULL,
    `isMarginTradingAllowed` CHAR NULL,
    `filterType_0` CHAR NULL,
    `minPrice` FLOAT NULL,
    `maxPrice` FLOAT NULL,
    `tickSize` FLOAT NULL,
    `filterType_1` CHAR NULL,
    `multiplierUp` TINYINT NULL,
    `multiplierDown` FLOAT NULL,
    `avgPriceMins_f1` TINYINT NULL,
    `filterType_2` CHAR NULL,
    `minQty_f2` FLOAT NULL,
    `maxQty_f2` FLOAT NULL,
    `stepSize_f2` FLOAT NULL,
    `filterType_3` CHAR NULL,
    `minNotional` FLOAT NULL,
    `applyToMarket` CHAR NULL,
    `avgPriceMins_f3` TINYINT NULL,
    `filterType_4` CHAR NULL,
    `limit_f4` TINYINT NULL,
    `filterType_5` CHAR NULL,
    `minQty_f5` FLOAT NULL,
    `maxQty_f5` FLOAT NULL,
    `stepSize_f5` FLOAT NULL,
    `filterType_6` CHAR NULL,
    `maxNumOrders` TINYINT NULL,
    `filterType_7` CHAR NULL,
    `maxNumAlgoOrders` TINYINT NULL,
    `permissions_0` CHAR NULL,
    `permissions_1` CHAR NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
 ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4  COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: and why did you copy the code without fixing it?

Comment: thanks  i understund  this little differents , but continue  to give me error  but now  in last part  ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`id`))' at line 72 in line 72  have     PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

Comment: Sorry for incorrect code. Backticks are necessary for all columns as well. Also PRIMARY KEY should be declared after columns within parethesis.